# Performing actual deduplication using LSH

Tags: data-mining, preprocessing, similarity, similar-documents

I have a huge dataset (>10M) of text files, which I try to de-duplicate - not only in terms of trivial duplicates, but also "near-duplicates", given some similarity threshold. I know that LSH (locality sensitive hashing) algorithm would be good option, but I don't know how to tackle the last phase of the processing.

Currently, I have the following:

1. Generate signatures for all of the text files
2. Compute hashes (perform the LSH)
3. Group documents from the same bucket & hash
4. From each group, find "similar" documents by comparing their similarity and applying the threshold.

The steps described above give me a large list of pairs of files, that were marked as "near duplicates". Next step is to actually remove those duplicates.

I have tried 3 approaches:

**#1** Use naive approach and drop every document that appeared in at least 1 pair, but that means I drop a lot of data (more than necessary).

**#2** Arbitrarily remove one file from each pair but then, it leaves some of the actual duplicates in place - see the example:

Input pairs (marked as duplicates):

```
A, B
A, C
C, D
E, F
```

After arbitrarily removing one file (e.g. the first one) from each pair I would get:

```
A, C, E
```

which actually leaves A, C in the dataset, but they were marked as duplicates.

**#3** Build a graph, treating pairs as edges, find connected components and take one file from each component. This is a great solution, but is really expensive computationally (both from the perspective of CPU and RAM) and does not scale to my dataset size.

**How to efficiently remove near duplicate files from my dataset while preserving as much data as possible?**